# Java matcher how to dynamically replace groups based on their value

Tags: java, regex, java-8

For a quick sample, I have the following string:

```
String s = "hey.there.man.${a.a}crazy$carl${a.b}jones
```

I also have the following method:

```
private String resolveMatchedValue(String s) {
    if(s.equals("a.a")) {
           return "A";
    else if(s.equals("a.b")) { 
           return "Wallet";
    else if(.....
    ....
 }
```

My pattern would be

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(.*?)\\}");
```

So for every substring in s that matches ${.*} I want there to be a call to the resolveMatchedValue method and it should be replaced with that. So ideally after the regex process s should be

```
 s = "hey.there.man.Acrazy$carl$Walletjones
```

I've looked at similar solutions but nothing that dynamically replaces the matched values based on the matched value, and have not been able to get it to work

edit: using java8

Comment: According to the code, shouldn't the output be `"hey.there.man.Acrazy$carlWalletjones"`?

Answer (score 10):

In order to capture just the right characters you should exclude right curly brace from your group `[^}]+`. In fact it's better practice to just include the specific pattern you are looking for to catch errors early:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([a-z]\\.[a-z]+)\\}");
```

The method `Matcher.replaceAll​(Function<MatchResult,String> replacer)` is designed to do exactly what you are asking for. The function passed to the method is given each match and returns a string to replace it with.

In your case:

```
pattern.matcher(input).replaceAll(mr -> resolveMatchedValue(mr.group(1)));
```

Will return a string with all substrings matching your pattern replaced.

Here's a working example that just uppercases the fields:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([[a-z]\\.[a-z])\\}")
    .matcher("hey.there.man.${a.a}crazy$carl${a.b}jones")
    .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1).toUpperCase()));
```

---

Prior to Java 9 an equivalent is:

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(result, resolvedMatchedValue(matcher.group(1)));
}
matcher.appendTail(result);
```

After which `result.toString()` holds the new string.

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately I am locked to java 8

Comment: @yoplayone That would have been useful information to have in your original question. I'll provide a pre-9 alternative.